# "Event.Type" Value Changed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just want to know as to what are some of the instances where the `event.type` value gets changed in javascript. Because I have this weird issue where I have two versions of a software (where version A is older than version B). There are no changes in the javascript code for both versions. They have the same code like this.

```
<select id="PlantColor" onchange="CheckKeyPress()">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

function CheckKeyPress() {
  alert(event.type); // For testing purposes only
  if (event.keyCode == 8){
    // Do something
  }
}
```

In version A, the value of the `event.type` is "keydown" while in version B, the value is "change" (but most of the time it is 'undefined').

Note that both versions are running in IE with the same version (and even older).

I need help in understanding this. I've also read this article ([Event accessing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html)), but it seems that I cannot arrive at a nice explanation to this.

Comment: show how do you accessing an `event.type` in your above code

Comment: In debug mode, when you type `event.type` it will get you its value.

Comment: ok, what is bothering you for the most part: value switching "keydown" - "change" OR 'undefined' `event` object ?

Comment: where you've added the `alert`, it will ALWAYS be `change`, if you just type into a console `event.type` then you'll get the latest event, if that was a key down event, then you'll get `keydown`, if no event is current you'll get `undefined`. This is a non-issue. Basically, unable to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/wL274pf0/